# What's the difference between @user.city and @city.user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

From what  I understand @city.user is the city that belongs to that particular user, and @user.city is an array of all the user(s) cities.. not sure If I understand this correctly though.

please help clear this up, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scenario #1
```

**One To Many Relationship : User and Cities**

```
@user.cities => Get all the `city` records for a particular `user`(@user) 
@city.user => Get the `user` record for a particular `city`(@city)
```

---

```
Scenario #2
```

**One To One Relationship : User and City**

```
@user.city => Get the `city` record for a particular `user`(@user)
@city.user => Get the `user` record for a particular `city`(@city)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your association, if you have the city object already obtain via an id or something and you want to find its user you could do `@city.user` to find out which user the city belongs to.  If you have a `User` and want to find all of their cities you would do `@user.cities` if it is a `has_many` association or `@user.city` if it is a `has_one` association.

Answer (score 0):

`@city.user` sends a `user` message to the `@city` object. `@user.city` sends a `city` message to the `@user` object.

In rails, if each user has an associated city, typically @user will be the object representing a user, and @user.city will return a city object associated with the user. Similarly, @city.users returns an array of users associated with the city, and an empty array if there are no users associated with the city.